# margin and padding are not showing any effect when Text is so lengthy

Tags: react-native

[image]

Below is the style for each list item,

```
itemStyle: {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   marginHorizontal: 24,
   paddingBottom: 25,
},
```

There is no `margin` applied right side of the screen and Text occupied all available space.

How to render the `Text` with in the `margin` or `padding` boundaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each `Text` component inside its own `View` component. The either give the `View` a padding or give the `Text` a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
itemStyle: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'row',
   marginHorizontal: 24,
   paddingBottom: 25,
},
```